# Unwanted `-c` flag used when installing R package with C++ code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

I am creating an R package `myCode` from a multithreaded C++ package  called `myCode`. (As you can see from the Makevars below, it requires linking to two existing C++ libraries, `library1` and `library2`.)

Using the Rcpp skeleton, I added all of the C++ code in `/src` and created this Makevars file to output the shared library `myCode.so`, whereby I've included the flags `-fPIC` and `-shared`:

```
LIBRARY1_DIR := ./library1/
LIBRARY2_DIR := ./library2/

ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR := $(realpath $(LIBRARY1_DIR))
ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR := $(realpath $(LIBRARY2_DIR))

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O3 -fexceptions -g -Wl,-rpath,$(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/lib/
LDLIBS := -I$(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/include/ -I$(ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR)/ -L$(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/lib/ -L$(ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR)/

all: library1 library2 myCode

.PHONY : myCode
myCode: file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.hh file3.cpp file4.hh file4.cpp file5.cpp file5.hh file6.hh file6.hh file7.cpp file7.hh
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) file1.cpp file2.cpp -o myCode.so $(ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR)/importfile1.a -lz -ldl -llibrary1 -lpthread -fPIC -shared


.PHONY : library1
library1:
    mkdir $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/build; cd $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/build; cmake ..; make; cd ../

.PHONY : library2
library2:
    cd $(ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR); ./configure; make; cd ../

#.PHONY : clean
clean:
     rm myCode.so; rm -rf $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/build; rm -rf $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/include; rm -rf $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/lib; rm -rf $(ABS_LIBRARY1_DIR)/bin; cd $(ABS_LIBRARY2_DIR); make clean;
```

This appears to compile correctly upon `library(devtools)` and `install_github("handle/myCode")`...until it starts to output these lines, which throw multiple `'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]` warnings until it breaks:

```
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O3 -fexceptions -g -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/ -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c file2.cpp -o file2.o
clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library/lib/: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O3 -fexceptions -g -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/ -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c file3.cpp -o file3.o
clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O3 -fexceptions -g -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/ -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c file4.cpp -o file4.o
clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O3 -fexceptions -g -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/ -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c file5.cpp -o file5.o
clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/private/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T/RtmpabyubP/devtools56576bf4fa65/username-myCode-368aaf6/src/library1/lib/: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from file6.cpp:1:
In file included from ./file6.hh:27:
./file7.hh:43:10: fatal error: 'lib/library1_header.h' file not found
#include "lib/library1_header.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [file6.o] Error 1
```

It appears the reason `'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]` is being thrown is due to `-c`. The option `-c` means "only compile, do not link", so any linker-related command line arguments are ignored. The code appeared to compile correctly until these lines.

As an independent test to check the above `Makevars` works, it does create the shared object `myCode.so` if I rename the above to `Makefile` and run `make`. This functions correctly, and `dyn.load("myCode.so")` works in R.

Why are the `clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG` run when installing an R package? Can I disable the `-c` flags, or should I rewrite the Makevars?

Comment: header file not found errors are not linker-related. they're include path related and that's the fatal error.

Comment: @hrbrmstr But the header files are found using `make` against the above as a Makefile. This compiles correctly it seems, and the paths are found. When installing via R, the R/Rcpp-related lines above are executed, and it then cannot find the header files.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that it's not a linker issue. You've got path issues that are going to be somewhat challenging to triage off-system, but others may have a quick fix.

Comment: R uses a _completely different scheme_ combining *your* `Makevars together with its Makefile snippet into a new Makefile (you do not explicitly see).  You probably trampled over some of its assumptions. In short: what you do is generally discouraged.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the help. I understand now---there are several Makefiles used `R CMD SHLIB`, and `Makevars` is only one.

Comment: Embedding additonal libraries is the most difficult deployment in an R packages.  It can be done, but it is not for the faint of heart.  And one probably should not start there. But with _a lot_ of effort you can drive this from `src/Makevars`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel 'And one probably should not start there.' Good point, but I'm not the boss calling the shots. :) One last question (to save a separate SO post): should one ever explicitly create a shared library like the above, e.g. `myCode.so`? The documentation `Writing R Extensions` appears to suggest no: `Note that Makevars should not normally contain targets...`

Comment: I think you want your embedded libraries to be static and then included in the one shared library so that _overall rule of one shared library named like the package_ holds---as that is all R will load for you. And it needs all symbols.  Maybe look at package Matrix for one example.  Good luck.